# exec command not working (php)

Tags: php, html, apache

I am working on a php app and this is my code:

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['PLAY']))
{
exec("open /Applications/Chess.app");
}
?>
<form method="post">
<button name="PLAY">Play Chess</button><br>

</form>
</html>
```

But when I run it, and press the button the Application does not open. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Also, where is "php.conf" on a Mac?

Comment: might just be the space after open. Ty: exec("open/Applications/Chess.app"); instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is an space before `/Applications/Chess.app`
try

`exec("open/Applications/Chess.app");`

Comment: I just tried that, and it's not working... Is the open command not supported by PHP? By the way, I checked the php.ini file and exec was not in the "disable_functions" section...